# Learn scheme if you have been programming with object oriented language for 20 years

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I've been a programmer for more than 20 years, and have programed in Pascal, C, C++, Java, Objective-C and C#.

Now, I want to learn Scheme and I'm having a lot of problems because I don't understand the structure of scheme programs. For example, yesterday I had a lot of problems with a program I did because I'm not sure if the problem was about if scheme doesn't allow to declare local variables in procedures.

Do you know any book, tutorials or resources to learn Scheme if you have been a programmer with those languages for so long?

Comment: You have been here for a while, surely you know this will be closed for soliciting recommendations. But while it's up... The classic and obvious choice is, naturally, [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html).

Comment: I will second that recommendation for SICP and while we are on that topic, someone modernized the book with new fonts and diagrams and stuff. It's pretty good. You can read it [online](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/).

Comment: You have programmed 6 algol dialects, 5 which are also C dialect, and now about to learn your SECOND programming language. Congrats. It will not be as easy as learning the same language with a few changes tough. People mention SICP and I prefer the [SICP videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Op3QLzMgSY&index=1&list=PLB63C06FAF154F047) where the wizards themselves show you how it's done.

Comment: Although concerned with R6RS scheme, this should be suitable for your stage of development: https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/ , particularly the introductory chapters.  By the way, you normally declare local variables in procedures using the 'let' form.

Comment: @ChrisVine Thanks for your comment. Reading the book SICP, I have read chapter 1 only, they said that we can declare variables using define. It's a mess!!! I will continue reading. By the way, the book SICP has a lot of exercices.

Comment: If you want to learn about programming using the scheme language (or at least, a version of the scheme language) then SICP is great.  If you want to learn the scheme language, then TSPL is in my view more appropriate.

Comment: @VansFannel FYI internal `define`s amount to a `letrec`. there are lots of free on-line books around, and also documentations to various implementations. TSPL, Teach Yourself a Scheme in Fixnum Days, PLAI by Krishnamurthi ... HTDP (a slow-going book aimed at beginners IIRC), ... EOPL (more broad), ... I'd disagree about Scheme being that different from Algol though. That would be Prolog, IMO.

Comment: @VansFannel Those exercises are important. Don't skip too many.

Comment: @WillNess: I'd say the biggest diff to Algol would be loops and macros. Algol had no concept of code-as-data, and also it depended a lot on explicit loops. Recursion was only introduced in Algol 60, over loud protests, and only because Dijkstra was a [sneaky bastard](https://vanemden.wordpress.com/2014/06/18/how-recursion-got-into-programming-a-comedy-of-errors-3/) :D Even now, most of the Algol family doesn't support TCO, making it impossible to rely on recursion for general-purpose looping. And you've been around SO long enough to know many people have trouble reasoning around recursion.

Comment: @Amadan thanks for the corrections! Didn't know the details. Still, TCR *is* loops, even if it looks differently. Goto is a function call is a goto. :) So, it depends under which magnifying glass to look at it -- as always. (recursion... it's really there to help *us* reason about stuff... too many bad textbooks in the world!)

Comment: Possible dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436351/scheme-for-object-oriented-programmers#4455585

Comment: Also: [CS 341 at Gettysburg College - Survey of Programming Languages:
Scheme for Java Programmers](http://cs.gettysburg.edu/~tneller/cs341/scheme-intro/index.html)